# How can I see the new web application option in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse at home, so I can program servlets. But it seems that I don't have the new Web applciation option, and many others.

Anyone knows what's the problem ? I install it first in Program Files then on C:\. Still the same problem. 
Btw, I am using Windows XP, with Eclipse Helios Service Release 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Eclipse did you download? There are several different distributions (Eclipse Classic, Eclipse for Java Developers, etc.).  You should make sure you downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2

Comment: You're very welcome. It's an easy mistake to make. Let me know if downloading the J2EE version works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you download the version that includes WTP (Web Tools Platform).  If not you will have to add the [appropriate features](http://archive.eclipse.org/technology/phoenix/demos/install-wtp/install-wtp.html).

Answer (score 1):

To program servlets you need Eclipse for Java EE developers, and DON'T forget a server like Apache Tomcat, or Glassfish, which I guess are not included with the original package of eclipse.

Personally I have manage to install Tomcat separately from Eclipse and then link it with the IDE. There are plenty of tutorials on youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX8xb-suzVg

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs